# Helper-related vows

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The *Bavli*, *Shabas* 93, brings several proofs to the proposition that מסייע אין בו ממש, one who helps is not tangible.

On the other hand, a general rule of vows (*n'darim*), mentioned e.g. in the *Bavli*, *N'darim* 13 *amud* 2, is that a vow about a דבר שאין בו ממש, intangible subject, is ineffectual.

Thus, it's impossible to make a vow about a helper (מסייע).

But as we know from the "בס״ד" scribbled atop papers, God is the ultimate מסייע. And the Torah (*Matos* 30:3–4) says we "should make a vow about God".

How do we resolve this contradiction?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).